# How to add a menu tab programmatically to a views page?

Tags: views, routes

I have a view page showing fields of an entity. The pages URL set in Views is

```
entity/%
```

Now I would like to add some tabs to this views pages that I can't generate with views it self, but have to do it programmatically. Si I tried:

```
function MY_MOODULE_menu() {
  $items['entity/%eid/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit',
    'page callback'   => 'MY_MODULE_entity_edit_callback',
    'access callback' => true,
    'page arguments' => array('eid'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 100,
  );  
  return $items;
}
```

As a menu of the type is `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` with the base path `entity/%` is created by the mentioned view, I thought this should simply work, but it does not: The tab does not show up. (Of course I cleared all caches). Did I got something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path hierarchy is based on string matching; so `entity/%eid/edit` doesn't come under `entity/%` (because `'%' != '%eid'`)

There are a couple of other issues, reading between the lines I reckon this is what you're going for:

```
function MY_MOODULE_menu() {
  $items['entity/%/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit',
    'page callback'   => 'MY_MODULE_entity_edit_callback',
    'access callback' => true,
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 100,
  );  
  return $items;
}

function MY_MODULE_entity_edit_callback($eid) {
  // ...
}
```